# VS Studio DataGridView error

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview

I am attempting to handle a local DB for a program I am doing, but I ran into this error that I can't get my head around! Whenever I attempt to edit a row in the gridview I get this error..

Screenshots:
https://i.gyazo.com/cc48a33863fada3e70e445620e6e9b2e.mp4
https://gyazo.com/5b184ea8aead4407e1bd2f0dd081b38c

Comment: Just for the record, "VS" stands for "Visual Studio", so what is this Visual Studio Studio you're using? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You row has multiple column. Free column is a not null column. 
When you add row, initialise the value of checkbox column.

`dataGridView1.Rows[2].Cells[3].Value = true;`

Comment: Rather than setting a value in the grid, set the `DefaultValue` property of the column in the `DataTable`.  I'd suggest that `False` would be the usual choice for a default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one event handler to your data grid and handle the error. Example

add the below code in your form loading event

```
            AddHandler DataGridView1.DataError, AddressOf DataErrorHandler
```

Replace DataGridView1 with your data grid name and then create the below function and handle your error.

```
Private Sub DataErrorHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs)
    'handle the error or do nothing.
End Sub
```